# Painting issue in Qt custom frameless window between monitors

Tags: c++, windows, qt, winapi, dwm

For one of my applications, I wanted to have a window customized under the Windows operating system (like Firefox, Avast, Microsoft Word, etc.). So I reimplemented some messages handling (`QWidget::nativeEvent ()`) from Win32 API, in order to preserve the functionality of AeroSnap, and others.

Although it works perfectly, when my custom window is transferred from one screen to another (I have two screens), a visual glitch appears (as you can see below). After the glitch appears, resizing the window, correct the bug. Moreover, after some debugging, I noticed that the Qt `QWidget::geometry()` is not the same as the geometry returned by Win32 API `GetWindowRect()` when the bug appears.

Both of my monitors are HD (1920x1080, so is not the difference of resolutions which cause the bug, but maybe the DPI difference ?). The glitch seems to appear when the window is moving between the two screens (when windows transfer the window to one screen to another ?).

Screenshot of the window without the glitch

[image]

Screenshot of the window with the glitch

[image]

The geometry reported initially by `QWidget::geometry()` is `QRect(640,280 800x600)`, by `QWidget::frameGeometry()` is `QRect(640,280 800x600)`, and by the Win32 `GetWindowRect()` is `QRect(640,280 800x600)`. So, the same geometry. But, after the window is moved between the two monitors, the geometry reported by `QWidget::geometry()` becomes `QGeometry(1541,322 784x561)`. The geometry reported by `QWidget::frameGeometry()` or `GetWindowRect()` is unchanged. Of course, after that, when the window is resized, the geometry is re correctly reported, and the painting issue dissapears. Conclusion, Qt seems to assume that a "appear" frame when the window is moved between two monitors.

The `BaseFramelessWindow` class implementation can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/T5gKQmWh). This is a Qt QMainWindow subclass re-implementing some Win32 API native events (`QWidget::nativeEvent()`).

So someone would be how to avoid this bug? Is this a Qt bug? I have tried many things, and nothing has really worked. And I can't find any mention of this problem on the internet (maybe I'm looking badly?).

Minimal example code:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include <QtWidgets/qapplication.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

```cpp
// MainWindow.h
#pragma once

#include <QtWidgets/qmainwindow.h>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = Q_NULLPTR);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event) override;
    bool nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result) override;
};
```

```cpp
// MainWindow.cpp
#include "MainWindow.h"

#include <QtGui/qpainter.h>

#include <Windows.h>
#include <Windowsx.h>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ::SetWindowLongPtr((HWND)winId(), GWL_STYLE, WS_POPUP | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MAXIMIZEBOX | WS_MINIMIZEBOX);
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);

    // Using GetWindowRect() instead of rect() seems to be a valid
    // workaround for the painting issue. However many other things
    // do not work cause of the bad geometry reported by Qt.
    RECT winrect;
    GetWindowRect(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(winId()), &winrect);
    QRect rect = QRect(0, 0, winrect.right - winrect.left, winrect.bottom - winrect.top);

    // Background
    painter.fillRect(rect, Qt::red);

    // Border
    painter.setBrush(Qt::NoBrush);
    painter.setPen(QPen(Qt::blue, 1));
    painter.drawRect(rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1));

    // Title bar
    painter.fillRect(QRect(1, 1, rect.width() - 2, 19), Qt::yellow);
}
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result)
{
    MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);

    switch (msg->message)
    {
    case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
        *result = 0;
        return true;
    case WM_NCHITTEST: {
        *result = 0;

        RECT winrect;
        GetWindowRect(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(winId()), &winrect);

        // Code allowing to resize the window with the mouse is omitted.

        long x = GET_X_LPARAM(msg->lParam);
        long y = GET_Y_LPARAM(msg->lParam);
        if (x > winrect.left&& x < winrect.right && y > winrect.top&& y < winrect.top + 20) {
            // To allow moving the window.
            *result = HTCAPTION;
            return true;
        }

        repaint();
        return false;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this exact error after and solved it by implementing Qt's `moveEvent` to detect screen changes and then call `SetWindowPos` to redraw the window in the same position.

An example would be:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    // rest of the class

private:

    QScreen* current_screen = nullptr;

    void moveEvent(QMoveEvent* event)
    {
        if (current_screen == nullptr)
        {
            current_screen = screen();
        }
        else if (current_screen != screen())
        {
            current_screen = screen();

            SetWindowPos((HWND) winId(), NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                         SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER |
                         SWP_NOOWNERZORDER | SWP_FRAMECHANGED | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
        }

    }
};
```

I'm not sure if the `current_screen == nullptr` clause is strictly needed, but I had trouble with multiple windows/dialogs without it (sometimes they would become unresponsive). I also do not know which flags for `SetWindowPos` are necessary.

I also cannot say whether this method is good practice, and it may cause problems elsewhere. Hopefully someone else can comment on this.

Either way it worked for me in a simple situation. Hopefully it provides a solution, or at least a starting point to try and solve this.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my life, I had the same issue after upgrading from 5.12 to 5.15,
In my case trying to resize the window fixed the glitch, when resizing the `WM_NCCALCSIZE ` mssage is sent to native event handler, here when you use `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` flag the `WM_NCCALCSIZE ` will sent to the window so the window size will be recalculated.
Anyway seems its a Qt related issue.

Comment: Thank you - used your code as reference in the bugreport: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-90701

Comment: I found that this solution does not handle screen changes coming from window snap, e.g. by using Win+left arrow. A more robust solution is to call `SetWindowPos` when the `QWindow::screenChanged` signal is emitted. This also avoids the black frame briefly showing after the screen is changed.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer: [How to integrate the Qt frameless window in Windows composer? (system shortcut doesnt works)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59017362/how-to-integrate-the-qt-frameless-window-in-windows-composer-system-shortcut-d/59059869#59059869)

I had the exact same issue with snapping between screens, as mentioned in the 3rd paragraph of that answer:

> I ran into some painting issues when snapping from one screen to another, but worked around that with a mask (notes in code comments). Would be nice to find a cleaner solution (it may qualify as a Qt bug actually).

And the workaround is at the bottom of the `FramelessWidget` code block in the `paintEvent()` method, after the long comment. I'll paste it here as well with a little context:

```cpp
  QStyleOption opt;
  opt.initFrom(this);
  // be sure to use the full frame size, not the default rect() which is inside frame.
  opt.rect.setSize(frameSize());  

      .....

  // Setting a mask works around an issue with artifacts when switching screens with Win+arrow
  // keys. I don't think it's the actual mask which does it, rather it triggers the region 
  // around the widget to be polished but I'm not sure. As support for my theory, the mask 
  // doesn't even have to follow the border radius.
  setMask(QRegion(opt.rect));
```

I don't see a `paintEvent()` in your code but perhaps you can do something similar from elsewhere.

BTW this may also give you a hint about why `QWidget::geometry()` isn't right... you probably want `QWidget::frameGeometry()`.

Comment: Using setMask() seems only to partially correct the issue. When using setMash(), a very ugly frame appears when the window is unfocused, and also when the window is reopen, the AeroSnap features do not work anymore (while without they work even when the window is reshown). But this give some ideas.

Comment: After some new debugging, the issue seems that Qt detect an inexistant frame between the two monitors. See my question update for more information.

Comment: @HubertGruniaux Well I do see you're using quite a different set of `SetWindowLongPtr()` flags and other features like the `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()` and such (my example was much simpler). I can see how `setMask()` could mess that up (though you could try setting it and removing it). I suspect the issue stems from the difference between `size()` and `frameSize()` and triggering a Qt re-paint may help. It would be useful to break down your example code to the minimum it takes to reproduce the issue, and post that complete code (including a `main()` with simple implementation example).

Comment: Minimal example code added. Where do you think I need to trigger a Qt re-paint ?

Comment: @HubertGruniaux Thanks for the example, sorry I just now had time to test it. But I can't reproduce the issue at all... not by moving the window with the mouse, nor with Aero-snap.  The painting comes out perfect each time.  What Qt version do you have, and which Windows? (Qt 5.12.6 here with Win7.)

Comment: If I add `setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);` in the MainWindow constructor, like my example had, then the painting issue is back -- which I can "fix" by adding `setMask(QRegion(QRect(QPoint(), frameGeometry().size())));` at the end of `paintEvent()`. But you don't seem to need `WA_TranslucentBackground` in the first place, so I'm not sure any of this is relevant.

Comment: Also, there is https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-81695 -- I don't know if it's related, but possibly. Are you using high-definition display(s)?  Also a related reproduction of this issue was made using one of the Qt examples, perhaps you want to try it: https://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2020-February/038809.html

Comment: I tested the Qt modified example, and there no problem on Windows 10 using Qt 5.13.1. And none of my displays are HDPI, so the QTBUG-81695 do not seem to be related.

Comment: In the example code I added a workaround, and that is because it works on your machine. But the workaround only corrects the painting issue of the window. But all the widgets are not correctly placed (Qt seems to report an incorrect geometry of the window, breaking the layout).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Qt does not handle the drawing of the window correctly when `WM_NCCALCSIZE` is modified!

I realized that you already have a work in progress, but i developed a parallel work that achieves your goals in a simple way that might interest you, it handles all the low level APIs of window for a border less window, while you can just use the `setCentralWidget` API and your widget will fill the whole window!

[image: QGoodWindow]

The header of `ExampleMinimal` (the clean example) is just:

```
#include <QGoodWindow>

class MainWindow : public QGoodWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();
};
```

See: https://github.com/antonypro/QGoodWindow